# Javascript clashing?

Tags: php, javascript, function

i have some validation code under all the HTML in my form which prevents seems to be preventing my checkbox validation code from working, i came to this conclusiom once i added /* */ around the code under my HTML (making it inactive) the checkbox validation code started working like normal. By the way both individual validations work fine. Could anyone possibly explain why this is happening because i need both validations to work? Here is my code :

```
<script>
  function validateCheckBoxes(theForm) {
    if (!theForm.declare.checked) {
      alert ('You must tick the checkbox to confirm the declaration');
      return false;
    } else {    
      return true;
    }
  }
</script>

<form name="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" id="eoi" onsubmit="return validateCheckBoxes(this);">
  <b>Post Code</b>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="post" name="post"><?php echo $msgp; ?>
  <b>Declaration</b>
  <input type="checkbox" name="declare" id="declare">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script>    
  var form = document.getElementById('eoi'),
    validNumbers = [2474,
                    2750,
                    2753,
                    2760,
                    2777];

  form.onsubmit = function() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById("post"),
        numb = parseInt(userInput.value, 10);

    if ( validNumbers.indexOf(numb) == -1 ) {
      alert("Please enter a correct postcode");
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }    
</script>
```

Comment: Put both checks in seperate functions and do `form.onsubmit = function () { return (check1() && check2()); };`. Can post full answer if required.

Comment: Did you look into [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) for errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the problem was you had two `onsubmit` handlers registered for the form, there the latest one will override the previous one.

Here I moved both the validations to one `onsubmit` handler, it first validates the postal code then for the declaration checkbox.

```
<form name="form" method="POST" action="" id="eoi">
    <b>Post Code</b>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="post" name="post"/>asdf
    <b>Declaration</b>
    <input type="checkbox" name="declare" id="declare"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

And

```
function validateCheckBoxes(theForm) {
    console.log('asdf')
    if (!theForm.declare.checked) {
        alert ('You must tick the checkbox to confirm the declaration');
        return false;
    } else {    
        return true;
    }
}

var form = document.getElementById('eoi'),
    validNumbers = [2474,
                    2750,
                    2753,
                    2760,
                    2777];

form.onsubmit = function() {

    var userInput = document.getElementById("post"),
        numb = parseInt(userInput.value, 10);
    if ( validNumbers.indexOf(numb) == -1 ) {
        alert("Please enter a correct postcode");
        return false;
    }

    return validateCheckBoxes(form);

}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mfWFj/)